# Remove image thumbnails which displayed at bottom on images

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

when i mouse hover on image, thumbnails are displayed at bottom on images i don't want that. how to delete that ? from prettyphoto.

jquery.prettyPhoto.js

[i have share my .js file, click here](http://itaxsmart.com//wp-content/themes/Avada/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js)

Comment: please ask specific problem and provide suitable code or working demo

Answer (score 0):

may be you could set following in your config for prettyPhoto:

```
'overlay_gallery': true
```

Answer (score 0):

You just change ....Select

```
pp_gallery{display:none !important;left:50%;margin-top:-50px;position:absolute;z-index:10000}
```

in prettyphoto.css and changed to

```
.pp_gallery{display:none;left:50%;margin-top:-50px;position:absolute;z-index:10000}
```